# Trying to Covert inches into feet and receive the error:- TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert inches into feet from weight-height datasets but have been receiving the error.

First Five value of column height

```
0    73.847017
1    68.781904
2    74.110105
3    71.730978
Name: Height, dtype: float64
```

Code

```
def inch_to_feet(inch):
    inch = float(inch[0])
    return (inch / 12)

df['Height In Feet'] = df["Height"].apply(lambda x:inch_to_feet(x))  
df
```

Error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-a26935c05d6f> in <module>
      3     return (inch / 12)
      4 
----> 5 df['Height In Feet'] = df["Height"].apply(lambda x:inch_to_feet(x))
      6 df

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4040             else:
   4041                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4042                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4043 
   4044         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-88-a26935c05d6f> in <lambda>(x)
      3     return (inch / 12)
      4 
----> 5 df['Height In Feet'] = df["Height"].apply(lambda x:inch_to_feet(x))
      6 df

<ipython-input-88-a26935c05d6f> in inch_to_feet(inch)
      1 def inch_to_feet(inch):
----> 2     inch = float(inch[0])
      3     return (inch / 12)
      4 
      5 df['Height In Feet'] = df["Height"].apply(lambda x:inch_to_feet(x))

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

This is my code and please mention some other technique as well if possible. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[0]` doe select first value of iterable in function:

```
def inch_to_feet(inch):
    inch = float(inch)
    return (inch / 12)

df['Height In Feet'] = df["Height"].apply(lambda x:inch_to_feet(x)) 

print (df)
      Height  Height In Feet
0  73.847017        6.153918
1  68.781904        5.731825
2  74.110105        6.175842
3  71.730978        5.977582
```

But better/ faster is avoid loops in function by converting to floats and divide by scalar like:

```
df['Height In Feet'] = df["Height"].astype(float) / 12

print (df)
      Height  Height In Feet
0  73.847017        6.153918
1  68.781904        5.731825
2  74.110105        6.175842
3  71.730978        5.977582
```

Comment: i have multiple value in column height. Using above code would give same value in each and every row. But what i want is to convert height into feet as per the inch value.

Comment: @PashupatiPariyar - Can you add first 5 values of column `Height` to question?

Comment: @PashupatiPariyar - thank you, for me working nice, added output from sample data. For you not?